# Database Update class using SQLCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to have advice on this use of base class and derived class. This all works but is it a good way to achieve a SOLID class?

```
  public class ProductRepository : GenericDataExport
  {
               private const string DB_TABLE = "[dbo].[ReplenEdit]";
               private int rowsUpdated;
               private int primaryKey;
               private string columnName;
               private int replenishAmount;

               public void SetUpdateReplenAmount(int primaryKey, int replenishAmount)
               {
                   this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
                   this.columnName = "ReplenishAmount";
                   this.replenishAmount = replenishAmount;
               }

               /// <summary> Method to check if database has been updated
               /// <para>Checks to see if the the Rows Updated field is greather than 0 
               /// This indicates that the database has had a least one row updated.</para>
               /// </summary>
               /// <returns>True or False</returns>
               public bool HasDatabaseBeenUpdated()
               {
                   return UpdateTableHelper.HasDatabaseBeenUpdated(this.rowsUpdated);
               }

               /// <summary> Create Update SQL statement and then update table using SQL Command
               /// </summary>
               /// <param name="conn">SQLConnection</param>
               protected override void ActionUpdateCommands(SqlConnection conn)
               {
                   string sql = CreateSQLStatement();

                   this.rowsUpdated = 0;

                   UpdateTable(conn, sql);
               }

           #region Class Implementation

                /// <summary> Method to update Database table with Replenish Amount
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="conn">SQLConnection object</param>
                /// <param name="sql">SQL Statement</param>
                private void UpdateTable(SqlConnection conn, string sql)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("@replenishAmt", SqlDbType.Int);
                        command.Parameters["@replenishAmt"].Value = this.replenishAmount;

                        this.rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                /// <summary> Method to create a SQL Statement to be used in the Update
                /// </summary>
                /// <returns>SQL Statement</returns>
                private string CreateSQLStatement()
                {
                    string updateValue = "@replenishAmt";

                    string updateTableSQL = UpdateTableHelper.CreateUpdateTableValue(updateValue, DB_TABLE,
                        this.columnName, this.primaryKey.ToString());
                    return updateTableSQL;
                }

          #endregion
            }

            public abstract class GenericDataExport
            {
                protected string dataExportError;
                readonly ConnectionStringSettings connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PiaReplen"];
                private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
                (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

                /// <summary> Gets the last error thrown by the UpdateDatabase method
                /// </summary>
                /// <returns>Data Export Error</returns>
                public string GetDataExportError()
                {
                    return dataExportError;
                }

                /// <summary> Checks to see if there is an error available after 
                /// UpdateDatabase has been called.
                /// </summary>
                /// <returns>True or False</returns>
                public bool HasDataExportFailed()
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataExportError))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                /// <summary> Open a connection to a SQL database
                ///  <para>as specified and call a virtual method
                /// (ActionUpdateCommand) that is overriden in the derived class</para>
                /// </summary>
                public void UpdateDatabase()
                {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            ActionUpdateCommands(conn);
                            log.Debug("Database Update Complete");
                        }
                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            this.dataExportError = string.Format("Error updating Database {0}", ex.Message);
                            log.Error("Error updating Database", ex);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                /// <summary> A virtual stub, that is defined in the derived class
                /// <para>Is where the update/insert commands are placed and called.</para>
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="conn">SQLConnection object</param>
                protected virtual void ActionUpdateCommands(SqlConnection conn)
                {}

            }

        public static class UpdateTableHelper
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Creates the SQL statement to use in the Update command
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="updateValue">The parameter placeholder to use in the update statement</param>
            /// <returns>SQL update statement</returns>
            public static string CreateUpdateTableValue(string updateValue, string dbTable, 
                string columnName, string primaryKey )
            {
                updateValue.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty("updateValue");

                dbTable.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty("dbTable");

                columnName.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty("columnName");

                primaryKey.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty("primaryKey");

                return string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET {1} = {2} where ID = {3}",
                    dbTable, columnName, updateValue, primaryKey);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets a parameter placeholder for a SQL update statement 
            /// depending on the Column Name passed.
            /// This is always the column name to lowercase prefixed with @
            /// <example>GetUpdateValue("ProductName") would return @productname</example>
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="columnName">Column name that parameter placeholder is for</param>
            /// <returns>Parameter Placeholder</returns>
            public static string GetUpdateValue(string columnName)
            {
                columnName.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty("columnName");

                return string.Format("@{0}", columnName.ToLower());
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Checks to see if the the Rows Updated field is greather than 0
            /// This indicates that the database has had a least one row updated.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>True or False</returns>
            public static bool HasDatabaseBeenUpdated(int rowsUpdated)
            {
                if (rowsUpdated > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

     public static class StringExtensions
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Extension methof that throws exception if string is null
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="field">This string</param>
            public static void ThrowIfNull(this string field, string fieldName)
            {
                if (field ==  null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("{0} cannot be null", fieldName));
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Extension methof that throws exception if string is null or empty
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="field">This string</param>
            public static void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(this string field, string fieldName)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("{0} cannot be null or empty", fieldName));
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Converts a string to sentence case.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="input">The string to convert.</param>
            /// <returns>A string</returns>
            public static string ToSentenceCase(this string input)
            {
                if (input.Length < 1)
                    return input;

                string sentence = input.ToLower();
                return sentence[0].ToString().ToUpper() +
                   sentence.Substring(1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProductRepository` is 60 lines, you don't need a `region`.

---

Don't abbreviate when you don't need to: there's no need to shorten `ReplenishAmount` to `Replen` in `SetUpdateReplenAmount`.

---

In UpdateTable you spend two lines on doing something that can be done in one:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@replenishAmt", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.replenishAmount;
```

But IMHO it's even worse that the parameter name -- `"@replenishAmt"` -- is repeated twice here and is also defined in `CreateSQLStatement`, when it clearly should be a `const` at the class level.

Moreover, why isn't `columnName` a const either?

---

But more importantly: all of your code is solving a problem that has already been solved by ORMs like NHibernate or Entity Framework. You have written a 60 line class that can do one single thing: update the field `ReplenishAmount` in the table `ReplenEdit`.

My advice: throw all of this away, implement a decent ORM and focus on the actual business logic.

Comment: I take your point on the constants, the ORM I avoid initially as the database was not setup when I started coding, but in hindsight I should maybe have used EF with Code First.

Comment: @PeterCampbell you may still be in luck, as [F# type providers for SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx) can work off DBML files you can generate with [SqlMetal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If you confine the repository code to a separate binary, you can write it in F# and still call it from your C# code in other binaries.

Answer (score 2):

It's a relatively small note, but this if statement can be replaced with a boolean return.

> ```
>            public bool HasDataExportFailed()
>             {
>                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataExportError))
>                 {
>                     return false;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     return true;
>                 }
>             }
> ```

```
public bool HasDataExportFailed()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataExportError);
}
```

And again here.

```
public static bool HasDatabaseBeenUpdated(int rowsUpdated)
{
    return (rowsUpdated > 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks, pretty obvious when you look at it, but I'll keep an eye out for this sort of thing in the future.